# conversion of direct indirect speech having "let me..."

Tags: reported-speech, direct-speech

> He said, "Let me ask you a question."

How can be this sentence be converted to indirect speech? Should it be:

> He said that he should ask me a question.

Comment: He said he should be allowed to ask me a question. let = allow

Answer (score 2):

He said, "Let me ask you a question."

**let** is asking for permission to do something- a request.

According to the Oxford Guide to English Grammar, section 270.1.a, we represent requests in reported speech by using **ask + object + to-infinitive**:

> He asked me to let him ask me a question.

That could probably be said more clearly in other words, but it is an exact reported speech version of the original sentence.

Answer (score 0):

*let* + *object pronoun* often expresses a suggestion or command.
You can use *should* or *ought to* to make the reported speech and *suggest* for the reporting verb:

> *He **suggested** that he **should/ought to** ask me a question.*